# Making a table with printf in c++

Tags: c++, printf, text-alignment

I'm trying to make a table like this.... (Just without the dots I used to separate the each item)

> Weekly Payroll:
>
> Name.....................Title.......Gross......Tax......Net
>
> Ebenezer Scrooge       Partner    250.00   ..62.25  .187.75
>
> Bob Cratchit           ..........Clerk       ......15.00    ....2.00  ..13.00

This is what my code looks like for this part....

```
for (int count=0; count < numberOfEmployees; count++)
{
    cout << "Employee: \n";
    cout << "\t Name: ";
    cin.getline (employees[count].name, EMPLOYEESIZE); 

    cout << "\t Title: ";
    cin.getline (employees[count].title, EMPLOYEESIZE);

    cout << "\t SSNum: ";
    cin >> employees[count].SSNum;

    cout << "\t Salary: ";
    cin >> employees[count].Salary;

    cout << "\t Withholding Exemptions: ";
    cin >> employees[count].Withholding_Exemptions; 
    cin.ignore();

    cout << "\n";
}


double gross;
double tax;
double net;
double adjusted_income;

cout << "\n";

cout << "Weekly Payroll: \nName \t \t Title \t Gross \t Tax \t Net \n";


for (int count=0; count < numberOfEmployees; count++)
{
    gross = employees[count].Salary;
    adjusted_income = subtraction_times (employees[count].Salary, employees[count].Withholding_Exemptions);
    tax = adjusted_income * .25;
    net = subtraction (gross, tax);

    printf ("\n%s", employees[count].name); 
}
```

I have the first part of the table(the name part), but after that I dont know now to do the rest of the table. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: You need to print header row before you enter the loop. Also take a look at setw and other "iomanipulators".

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you _have_ to use `printf`?

Comment: Most probably it's part of the assignment :^)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use `printf` with left-justify flag (-).

```
printf("%-10s", "title"); // this will left-align "title" in space of 10 characters
```

Here is a sample program:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name = "Bob Cratchit";
    string title = "Clerk";
    float gross = 15;
    float tax = 2;
    float net = 13;

    printf("%-25s%-20s%-10s%-10s%-10s\n", "Name", "Title", "Gross", "Tax", "Net"); 
    printf("%-25s%-20s%-10.2f%-10.2f%-10.2f\n", name.c_str(), title.c_str(), gross, tax, net); 
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Name                     Title               Gross     Tax       Net
Bob Cratchit             Clerk               15.00     2.00      13.00
```

Comment: James, what would be a maintainable alternative?

Answer (score 5):

The most obvious question is: why use printf, when other tools are more
adapt?  Another question, often forgotten, is what is the (final) output
medium?  If the text is going to end up on a printer or in a text box in
a windowing system, you may have your work cut out for you.  The fonts
on such systems are rarely fixed width, so you'll have to take into
account the width of the individual characters.  For output to a
printer, I would suggest outputting LaTeX and then postprocessing it.
For outputting to a window, the library you're using probably has some
sort of table component which will do the formatting for you.

If you're outputing to some fixed width font device—a teletyp, for
example, then you can either use iostream manipulators or user defined
types.  (There's no way to do this cleanly with `printf`—you need
iostreams.)  Abstractly speaking, defining types like `Name`, `Title`
and `MonitaryAmount` is the cleanest solution.  In which case, you just
define an appropriate `<<` operator for the type.  Using a user defined
type for name and title, instead of just `std::string`, may be overkill,
however, and the manipulator approach may be preferred. (In a very large
application, where the separate types would be justified, you're likely
to need output in different contexts, and want manipulators to specify
them as well.)

In the simplest solution, you could get by with just two manipulators:
`TextField` and `MoneyField`: each manipulator would take the field
width as an argument to the constructor, and set the appropriate format
fields in its `<<` operator, e.g.:

```
class TextField
{
    int myWidth;
public:
    TextField( int width ) : myWidth( width ) {}
    friend std::ostream&
    operator<<( std::ostream& dest, TextField const& manip )
    {
        dest.setf( std::ios_base::left, std::ios_base::adjustfield );
        dest.fill( ' ' );
        dest.width( manip.myWidth );
        return dest;
    }
};
```

and

```
class MoneyField
{
    int myWidth;
public:
    MoneyField( int width ) : myWidth( width ) {}
    friend std::ostream&
    operator<<( std::ostream& dest, MoneyField const& manip )
    {
        dest.setf( std::ios_base::right, std::ios_base::adjustfield );
        dest.setf( std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::floatfield );
        dest.fill( ' ' );
        dest.precision( 2 );
        dest.width( manip.myWidth );
        return dest;
    }
};
```

(Practically speaking, it's probably better to use a class for Money.
You'll want special rounding rules for multiplication, for example; if
you're calculating tax, in fact, you'll probably need to use some sort
of decimal type, rather than `double`, in order to meet legal
requirements as to how it is calculated.)

Anyway, given the above manipulators, you can write something like:

```
TextField  name( 15 );
TextField  title( 8 );
MoneyField gross( 8 );
MoneyField tax( 6 );
MoneyField net( 8 );
for ( std::vector< Employee >::const_iterator employee = employees.begin();
        employee != employees.end();
        ++ employee ) {
    std::cout << name  << employee->name()
              << title << employee->title()
              << gross << employee->salary()
              << tax   << calculateTax( employee->salary() )
              << net   << calculateNet( employee->salary() )
              << std::endl;
}
```

(This assumes that you've cleaned up the rest to make it idiomatic and
maintainable C++ as well.)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using tabs to position at specific columns, use standard stream [I/O manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip). To be more specific, check out [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [`std::left`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left).

Something like this:

```
std::cout << std::left << std::setw(25) << "Name" << std::setw(12) << "Title"
          << std::setw(11) << "Gross" << std::setw(9) << "Tax" << "Net\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not mix `printf` and `cout` - they use different buffering mechanisms and can lead you into all sort of problems. As you are using C++ stick with `cout`. Look into `setw` and other manipulators to format the output as required.

Comment: When you say "don't mix" do you mean don't interleave `printf` and `cout` statements in a single block of code? Or do you mean choose one for your entire code project (i.e., for every source file involved in your project where you're outputting to `std::out`)?